# Cannot insert widgets in CMS page or static block, somebody know what could be wrong?

Tags: magento2, cms-block

using **Magento version 2.3.5-p1**.
Have the follwing problem and do not know why this is not working anymore.
Editing a block, disable editor and clicking on "insert widget" I get a

> 404 page not found screen.

On the log I got a debug.log containing the following:

`[2020-07-02 21:48:14] main.DEBUG: URI '/admin/cms/page/edit/page_id/6/key/9cda62bd1db41b6a327d51c1b2b9abb85a93b75f938498bdf2b8b897c40b9247/widget_target_id/cms_page_form_content/mode/new?isAjax=true'' cannot be accessed with POST method (Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\Edit) [] [] [2020-07-02 21:48:14] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\Edit\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at D:\\WebMagentoAktuell\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\Request\\HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []`

Any idea what could cause this error?

Because of this, I cannot insert a widget.

Please help
Best regards,
Jürgen